# Outlook add-in created in C# (.NET 6.0) not showing in outlook ribbon

Tags: .net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I was having my outlook desktop add-in in .NET framework version 4.8.
Recently, I have migrated it to 6.0.

It's having 4 projects :

- Project 1 (WPF Class library)
- Project 2 (WPF Class library)
- Project 3 (C++ Shim Project)
- Project 4 (WPF Application)

Everything building successfully. Add-in is getting registered on registry with success.
Add-in is not getting disabled.

But still I am not able to see my add-in on outlook ribbon.

Don't know what is exactly happening.

Comment: Is your add-in loaded at all? have you tried debugging the add-in?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Yes i have tried to debug. But no breakpoints were hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSTO like any other frameworks for developing COM add-ins doesn't support .Net core. .Net standard can't be used for developing COM add-ins, you need to use any .Net framework versions, but not Core (.net standard). If you try to create a new VSTO add-in for Outlook you will not find any .Net Standard (Core) versions in the list of available target .net versions:

[image: .net framework versions]

Comment: Its not an VSTO add-in.

Comment: Looking at the C++ Shim project I understood that, but it doesn't matter actually.